# Javascript equivalent to creating nonce value from Value

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, groovy, amadeus

I have this Java code/Groovy Code:

```
import org.apache.ws.security.util.Base64;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
def generate_nonce() {  
    def random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
    random.setSeed(System.currentTimeMillis());
    def nonceValue = new byte[16];
    random.nextBytes(nonceValue);
    return Base64.encode(nonceValue);
}
```

I'm trying to create the equivalent in Javascript-NodeJs. The utilities/SHA1PRNG is this module https://github.com/bombworm/SHA1PRNG. Can someone help?

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const secureRandom = require('./utilities/SHA1PRNG');

function generate_nonce () {
    let nonce = secureRandom(Date.now().toString());
    let nonceValue = crypto.randomBytes(16);
    // incomplete part, below does not work
    // return nonceValue.update(secureRandom).toString('base64');
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I've discovered the answer to my questions. Hopefully, this will help someone in the future.

The short:

```
const secureRandom = require('./utilities/SHA1PRNG');
function generate_nonce () {
    const nonceValue = secureRandom(Date.now());
    // I've added a type check in the SHA1PRNG module, it's local rather than installed through npm, this was to remove the toString.
    return nonceValue.toString('base64');
};
```

The long:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html#nextBytes(byte[])
the groovy/java code is selecting a particular algorithm to generate random bytes.  It's using the milliseconds as the foundation to generate those bytes aka the seed. Right after that, the byte[16] is generating an array to hold the 16 bytes. The random.nextBytes is filling that array with the random bytes generated from the algorithm. It's then encoding the array and returning it.

We are doing the equivalent in javascript. Its return a 16-byte Buffer based on the seed we supplied which is the number of milliseconds. We are then encoding that array and returning it.